# Array to string conversion in

Tags: php

Somebody solve my problem. Update query not work.
Error in Update query this step... Array to string conversion $query .= "image = '{$image}' "; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $folder="uploads/";

    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    $image =str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
    move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$image);

    $firstname      = $_POST["firstname"];
    $lastname       = $_POST["lastname"];
    $address1       = $_POST["address1"];
    $address2       = $_POST["address2"];
    $city           = $_POST["city"];
    $state          = $_POST["state"];
    $zipcode        = $_POST["zipcode"];
    $email          = $_POST["email"];
    $country        = $_POST["country"];
    $phone          = $_POST["phone"];
    $image          = $_FILES["image"];
    $username       = $_POST["username"];
    $passwordold    = $_POST["oldpassword"];
    $passwordone    = $_POST["passwordone"];
    $passwordtwo    = $_POST["passwordtwo"];
    $sessions       = $_SESSION['admin_id'];


    $query  = "UPDATE user SET ";
    $query .= "firstname = '{$firstname}', ";
    $query .= "lastname = '{$lastname}', ";
    $query .= "addressone = '{$address1}', ";
    $query .= "addresstwo = '{$address2}', ";
    $query .= "city = '{$city}', ";
    $query .= "state = '{$state}', ";
    $query .= "zipcode = '{$zipcode}', ";
    $query .= "email = '{$email}', ";
    $query .= "country = '{$country}', ";
    $query .= "phone = '{$phone}', ";
    $query .= "image = {$image} ";
    $query .= "WHERE id = {$sessions} ";
    $query .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES);
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: What type of column is `image` in the table? Should be a blob.

Comment: Take time to read the docs for [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

Comment: My guess is you actually want to change `$image = $_FILES["image"];` to `$image = $image;` as you want the new file name instead of the original name. Or just remove that line and just use the value set in `$image =str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);`

Answer (score 0):

$_FILES["image"] is an array. You can only pass string in sql queries. May be you need to serialize the array and then store it in the database.